# Visual Basic 2010 issue in Clearing Text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Basic 2010.
I have create a simple Textbox which can take multiline input with three buttons clear Text,Date and Show Message.
Assuming the TextBox contains some text.
I want to clear the textbox by clicking "Clear Text" button.
Button1 is the name of the control "Clear Text"
  here is the code i used.

```
        Private Sub Button1_Click()
               Button1.Text = ""
        End Sub
```

But when i start debugging and click "Clear Text" instead of Textbox getting Cleared the "Clear Text" Control button itself gets Cleared.

Thankyou

Comment: Is there a handler attached to that click method?  Seems pretty obvious what is happening if the buttons' text is getting cleared.

Comment: Yes it is i just formatted it here.

Comment: Well, I suggest in the future you don't do that.  Copy the real code next time that duplicates the problem for us.  It will help you get better answers.

Comment: Ok sure. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are clearing the text from button1.
replace Button1.Text = ""
 with textbox1.text=""
(textbox1 or the real name of your text box control...)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Clear()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

> Clears all the content from the text box.

So that would look like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Clear()
End Sub
```